# White space in between banner image and menu bar on site-only 1080px screen and lower. How to fix?

Tags: html, css, menubar, banner, responsive

i am working on this site:

http://www.aquidneckislanddaycamp.com/AIDC2/index.html

i used a template and got everything functioning pretty well, except that when i size the screen down, anything lower than 1080 pixels, the banner leaves a space in between itself and the menu bar...you can see it when you size the above link down.  i have tried writing different things in the media query section...i am not sure how to fix this.  i am newer at code and trying to learn.  can anyone help?  i did not post the css or the html because i know it is easy to see with web developer tools...but i can if anyone would like me to. thank you.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: i apologize.  i will try my best to word my issue better next time, and will include the source code and css in the future with pictures.  i am mildly autistic and communication is something i will always struggle with, but the photos will make it very clear and i will try better next time.  i want to thank Sebastian Olsen....that code that you gave solved my problem.  the site is now fully functioning on all sizes thanks to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: block` to the `img` inside your banner container.

Comment: phew! but can you explain why it shows the border if we open the image alone in browser too?

Comment: @NabeelKhan Images are default inline elements to be used inside blocks of text, the image has by default a little bit of bottom margin because of that. Think of the image within a block of text, the image needs spacing underneath so that text has breathing space between it and the image.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using bootstrap please check this link to get the default media queries for different screen sizes [Bootstrap Media Queries](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  i am newer at web design and have begun researching bootstrap.  this is a really great idea.  hoping i can understand it!